# ActionScript Read Sprite's Graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, properties, get, sprite

how can i retrieve the set graphics properties of a sprite?  for example, in the code below, i'd like to get the color of the sprite, also it's rounded corners setting and other graphics attributes.

```
var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
sp.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.75);
sp.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 300, 50, 10, 10);
sp.graphics.endFill();

addChild(sp);
trace(sp.graphics.color);  //pseudo trace - this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain this is not possible.  However, there are certainly other ways to do this.  What about having a valueObject for each property that stores the values used.  Then you could have a GraphicalDisplayObject that you either inherit from or use via composition.  For instance:

```
package {
    class FillVO extends Object {
        public var fill_color:Number = 0xFF0000;
        public var fill_opacity:Number = 0.75;
    }
}

package {
    import FillVO;
    class GraphicalDisplayObject extends Sprite {
        public var fill_vo:FillVO;
        public function beginFill($vo:FillVO) {
            graphics.beginFill($vo.fill_color, $vo.fill_opacity);
        }
        ...
    }
}

package {
    import GraphicalDisplayObject;
    class ObjectWithGraphicalProperties extends Sprite {
        public var gfx:GraphicalDisplayObject;
        public function ObjectWithGraphicalProperties() {
            gfx = new GraphicalDisplayObject();
            addChild(gfx);
        }
        public function beginFill($color:Number, $opactity:Number) {
            var fill_vo:FillVO = new FillVO();
            fill_vo.fill_color = $color;
            fill_vo.fill_opacity = $opacity;
            gfx.beginFill(fill_vo);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Then to use it...

```
var obj:ObjectWithGraphicalProperties = new ObjectWithGraphicalProperties();
addChild(obj);
obj.beginFill(0xffff00, .2);
...
...
trace(obj.gfx.fill_vo.fill_color);
```

This is obviously via composition, and you would need to write the additional proxied methods and corresponding valueObjects... but it should work.

Comment: Looks like that is "similar" to senocular's approach - http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1939945&postcount=176